# How unpack the array with object?

Tags: javascript

How to get from this array

```
[{"one": "deleted"}, {"two": "added"}]
```

this result

```
{"one": "deleted", "two": "added"}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Object.assign` for that

```js
const data = [{"one": "deleted"}, {"two": "added"}]

console.log(Object.assign({}, ...data))
```